# How to find get keys value from object?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i have collect data from service in interface type object but not able to find or filter key from this object.

the error is ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userAccess' of undefined
    at ShowBranchuserComponent.push../src/app/pages/userrelated-page/show-branchuser/show-branchuser.component.ts.ShowBranchuserComponent.ngOnInit (show-branchuser.component.ts:42)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserrelatedService } from '../userrelated-page.service';
import { UserRegister } from 'app/shared/model/Register';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouteInfo } from 'app/shared/sidebar/sidebar.metadata';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-show-branchuser',
  templateUrl: './show-branchuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-branchuser.component.scss']
})
export class ShowBranchuserComponent implements OnInit {
  showuser: UserRegister;
  pname;
  regularForm: FormGroup;
  access:RouteInfo[];

  constructor(private _AR:ActivatedRoute, 
    private _router: Router, 
    private _userRelated: UserrelatedService,
    private _fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this._AR.params.subscribe(data=>{this.pname = data['id']})
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userRelated.getOneUser(this.pname).subscribe(data=> this.showuser = data);
    this.regularForm = this._fb.group({
      'id': [{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'name':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'username':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'role':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'status':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'state':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'pincode':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'mobileno':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'address':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
    });
   this.access = this.showuser.userAccess; // here showing error 
    console.log(this.showuser);
  }

  onReactiveFormSubmit(){

  }
}
```

Comment: this.showuser will be undefined as you are not setting any value to it.

Comment: Console.log your `showuser` and check what value are you getting in your `userAccess` , is seems it is `undefined` with no value

Comment: @Ritesh he is assigning value in his `subscribe`  call back

Comment: @Ritesh check wentjun answer he clears the problem with proper details.

Answer (score 4):

Returning an observable value is an asynchronous operation. Because of that, the block of code you have written will fail as `showuser` will be undefined at that point. To further understand this, you should read up on JavaScript's queue and [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

You should be assigning `showuser.userAccess` to the `access` property within the `.subscribe()` block instead:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._userRelated.getOneUser(this.pname).subscribe(data=> {
      this.showuser = data;
      this.access = this.showuser.userAccess; 
      console.log(this.showuser);
     ]);
    this.regularForm = this._fb.group({
      'id': [{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'name':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'username':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'role':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'status':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'state':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'pincode':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'mobileno':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      'address':[{value:'', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You insert data into `this.showuser` in subscribe function so this is an async operation but you are trying to use the data in sync operation. async operations take time for the data to come back from the server to the client so what you are trying to do is to insert data into `this.acess` before the data arrives.

To solve this you can insert the data to `this.acess` inside the subscribe function